# How do you handle changes to xml files across different feature branches?

Tags: metadata, xml, version-control

We have different teams all working in the same Salesforce instance. While these teams usually have their own permission sets/objects/whatever that they work in, there are times when we find ourselves all working on the same piece of metadata.

We have a feature branch for every story so when different teams are working on different stories that are all working with permission set X, we're having a hard time merging and resolving the differences across the different teams when the sprint is over and we're starting to complete these pull requests.

I've quickly realized that using the git merge will just entirely leave entire blocks of xml out, or merge some pieces but leave others completely out.

How do other teams deal with this issue? Is our process bad in handling changes to xml files? Are there tools out there that'll merge these xml files accurately? What am I missing?

Comment: Just as an FYI, I've voted to close this question simply because this is a highly opinion based topic. There are a huge number of tools and approaches to manage this but it's probably broader than the scope of this forum sorry.

Comment: @CallumMacErlich Could you at least tell me what some of those opinions are? I'd love to read up on different approaches to take to my team.

Comment: This is probably one of the best resources I've seen recently: [Salesforce Git Branching Strategies](https://www.pablogonzalez.io/salesforce-git-branching-strategies/). It's well worth a read, and as a starting point I'd agree with the recommendation to start with GitFlow and build from there (but obviously depends on your situation).

Comment: Yep. Plenty of opinion here. E.g. the article says "Git branching strategies are only needed if you are doing Git-based deployments". I disagree. Git branching is required if you have large changes to make that cannot be incrementally deployed without disrupting parallel developments. Branching is essential in Salesforce ISV development where git-based deployments effectively never happen (at least not in the way the author meant).

Comment: The article also makes no mention of scratch orgs, instead expecting long-lived developer orgs. #shudder# For me that is so last decade...

Comment: You should look at products like Gearset that I know does semantic analysis and merge conflicts within "container"-type XML files like Profile and Permission Sets - something that Git would think of as a merge conflict, Gearset will realize is just two changes to independent parts of the same XML file

Comment: Ironically, it's because of xml merge conflicts in gearset that made me ask this question haha